# How can I create a random unique token and use it to verify an email address for a user in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email-verification

I have all the logic written for my user registration except for email verification.  Via my researched I learned that, simplifyingly, I need to create a random unique token and include that token in a link sent to the email address that is to be verified.

How can I create this random token and what how should I process the request from the activation link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Nuget but you can code yourself for sending an activation link and processing it.
The steps are:

1) Generate random unique token and save it in your database. For generating unique token you can use UUID in Java as

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

2) Include that token, encrypt it (not necessary though) and send it to the email ID.

example: www.xyz.com/activation?action=a273jsjh2718sjhdj271jgsdjaj28jh

3) When ever the user clicks that link, invoke the method for further processing in your controller. Map the url to your method in your controller.

Here is the [example](http://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email) done using Spring Framework. I hope it helps.

PS: I don't know whether it is good practice for production. I just tried to help you.

Comment: You can use generate uuid and send it with the url.

Comment: I just edited my tags to include 'C#' as this is a C# project (sorry).  I didn't do that originally because last time I asked a general web development question I met a lot of criticism for using language specific tags.

Comment: In c# also you can generate GUID as 
String token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

And the remaining logic is same

Comment: For the record, when I mentioned Nuget, it was only to point out that I knew of ways to send emails, and that 'how to send an email' wasn't a part of my question. :b I only mention this because I've revised the question for future viewers and the Nuget thing is kind of confusing and also makes me look like a noob.